# Reading XML from REST post request using Springboot

Tags: java, xml, rest, spring-boot

I'm trying to consume XML received via REST webservice using Springboot, I'm new to this so hoping it's fairly trivial mistake I'm making.

I think the XML may be poorly structured but I have the following....

```
<ResultDetailsRequestModel>
<tournament>Premier League</tournament>
<fixture_date>2018-08-10</fixture_date>
<description>result</description>
<home_team>
    <team_name>Man Utd</team_name>
    <score>2</score>
    <ht_score>1</ht_score>
    <possession>46.3</possession>
    <shots_on_target>6</shots_on_target>
    <shots_off_target>1</shots_off_target>
    <corners>2</corners>
    <player gk="true" position="G" number="1">D de Gea</player>
    <player position="D" number="2">V Lindelof</player>
</home_team>
</ResultDetailsRequestModel>
```

But the player details are not being read, I get the following when I do a toString on the data I've received.

```
ResultDetailsRequestModel(tournament=Premier League, fixture_date=Fri Aug 10 01:00:00 BST 2018, description=result, home_team=TeamResultXML(team_name=Man Utd, score=2, ht_score=1, possession=46.3, shots_on_target=6, shots_off_target=1, corners=2, players=null))
```

I can get the information when I surround the player tags with

```
<players> ... </players>
```

but changing the XML has a big impact elsewhere so hoping to fix with XML as is.

My code looks as follows...

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("results") // http://localhost:8888/results
public class ResultsController {

    @PostMapping(
            consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE },
            produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }
    )
    public String createBets(@RequestBody ResultDetailsRequestModel resultDetails) {
        return "Received details: " + resultDetails.toString();
    }
}
```

```
@Data
@XmlRootElement(name="ResultDetailsRequestModel")
public class ResultDetailsRequestModel {
    private String tournament;
    private Date fixture_date;
    private String description;
    private TeamResultXML home_team;

}
```

```
@Data
@XmlRootElement(name="home_team")
public class TeamResultXML implements Serializable {
    private String team_name;
    private int score;
    private int ht_score;
    private double possession;
    private int shots_on_target;
    private int shots_off_target;
    private int corners;
    @XmlElement(name="player")
    private List<PlayerXML> players;

}
```

```
@Data
@XmlRootElement(name="player")
public class PlayerXML implements Serializable {
    @XmlAttribute(name="gk")
    private boolean goalkeeper;

    @XmlAttribute(name="position")
    private String position;

    @XmlAttribute(name="number")
    private int number;

    @XmlAttribute(name="sub")
    private String sub;

    @XmlValue
    private String value;
}
```

Data I receive....

```
ResultDetailsRequestModel(tournament=Premier League, fixture_date=Fri Aug 10 01:00:00 BST 2018, description=result, home_team=TeamResultXML(team_name=Man Utd, score=2, ht_score=1, possession=46.3, shots_on_target=6, shots_off_target=1, corners=2, players=null))
```

The @Data annotation is project Lombok so creates the getters, setters etc.

Comment: *FYI:* You only need `@XmlRootElement` on the class for the root XML tag, i.e. the first class. Only specifying it there helps document that *it* is the root element, the others are not.

Answer (score 1):

When I try your code, I get errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 7 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String PlayerXML.value
        at PlayerXML
        at private java.util.List TeamResultXML.players
        at TeamResultXML
        at public TeamResultXML ResultDetailsRequestModel.getHome_team()
        at ResultDetailsRequestModel
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String PlayerXML.getValue()
        at PlayerXML
        at private java.util.List TeamResultXML.players
        at TeamResultXML
        at public TeamResultXML ResultDetailsRequestModel.getHome_team()
        at ResultDetailsRequestModel
Class has two properties of the same name "players"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.util.List TeamResultXML.getPlayers()
        at TeamResultXML
        at public TeamResultXML ResultDetailsRequestModel.getHome_team()
        at ResultDetailsRequestModel
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.util.List TeamResultXML.players
        at TeamResultXML
        at public TeamResultXML ResultDetailsRequestModel.getHome_team()
        at ResultDetailsRequestModel
Class has two properties of the same name "goalkeeper"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public boolean PlayerXML.isGoalkeeper()
        at PlayerXML
        at private java.util.List TeamResultXML.players
        at TeamResultXML
        at public TeamResultXML ResultDetailsRequestModel.getHome_team()
        at ResultDetailsRequestModel
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private boolean PlayerXML.goalkeeper
        at PlayerXML
        at private java.util.List TeamResultXML.players
        at TeamResultXML
        at public TeamResultXML ResultDetailsRequestModel.getHome_team()
        at ResultDetailsRequestModel
Class has two properties of the same name "number"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public int PlayerXML.getNumber()
        at PlayerXML
        at private java.util.List TeamResultXML.players
        at TeamResultXML
        at public TeamResultXML ResultDetailsRequestModel.getHome_team()
        at ResultDetailsRequestModel
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private int PlayerXML.number
        at PlayerXML
        at private java.util.List TeamResultXML.players
        at TeamResultXML
        at public TeamResultXML ResultDetailsRequestModel.getHome_team()
        at ResultDetailsRequestModel
Class has two properties of the same name "position"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String PlayerXML.getPosition()
        at PlayerXML
        at private java.util.List TeamResultXML.players
        at TeamResultXML
        at public TeamResultXML ResultDetailsRequestModel.getHome_team()
        at ResultDetailsRequestModel
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String PlayerXML.position
        at PlayerXML
        at private java.util.List TeamResultXML.players
        at TeamResultXML
        at public TeamResultXML ResultDetailsRequestModel.getHome_team()
        at ResultDetailsRequestModel
Class has two properties of the same name "sub"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String PlayerXML.getSub()
        at PlayerXML
        at private java.util.List TeamResultXML.players
        at TeamResultXML
        at public TeamResultXML ResultDetailsRequestModel.getHome_team()
        at ResultDetailsRequestModel
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String PlayerXML.sub
        at PlayerXML
        at private java.util.List TeamResultXML.players
        at TeamResultXML
        at public TeamResultXML ResultDetailsRequestModel.getHome_team()
        at ResultDetailsRequestModel
Class has two properties of the same name "value"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String PlayerXML.getValue()
        at PlayerXML
        at private java.util.List TeamResultXML.players
        at TeamResultXML
        at public TeamResultXML ResultDetailsRequestModel.getHome_team()
        at ResultDetailsRequestModel
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String PlayerXML.value
        at PlayerXML
        at private java.util.List TeamResultXML.players
        at TeamResultXML
        at public TeamResultXML ResultDetailsRequestModel.getHome_team()
        at ResultDetailsRequestModel

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:445)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:277)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1123)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:462)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
    at Test8.main(Test8.java:17)
```

When I fix that by adding `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` to all 3 classes, I get expected output:

```
ResultDetailsRequestModel [tournament=Premier League, fixture_date=Fri Aug 10 00:00:00 EDT 2018, description=result, home_team=TeamResultXML [team_name=Man Utd, score=2, ht_score=1, possession=46.3, shots_on_target=6, shots_off_target=1, corners=2, players=[PlayerXML [goalkeeper=true, position=G, number=1, sub=null, value=D de Gea], PlayerXML [goalkeeper=false, position=D, number=2, sub=null, value=V Lindelof]]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response Andreas, I added the XmlAccessorType annotation at the class level to all 3 classes but the players details is still null.  Did you make any other changes?  Do the annotations go at the class level?

Comment: @user11609657 I removed `@XmlRootElement` on the two classes, added `@XmlAccessorType` to all 3 classes, replaced `@Data` with actual getter and setter methods (generated by Eclipse), and added `toString()` methods (generated by Eclipse). I believe I removed `Serializable` too, since that has nothing to do with XML serialization. I was testing on jdk1.8.0_181 on Windows.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I'll give that a go and let you know how I get on.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I made the changes you suggested but I'm still getting the same issues.  The only difference is I'm using java 11 instead of 8, I'm also using Intellij instead of Eclipse.  Strange.